# C Programming - Struct

Tags: c, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct s {  
  char *a1;
  int a;
};

int main(){
struct   s p={"asdv",11};
struct   s p1=p;

p1.a1="vshaj";
printf("%d %s",p.a,p.a1);
}
```

In above program
Does p1.a1 and p.a1 point to same memory address?

Answer (score 1):

1) Struct p1 is a *copy* of p

2) HOWEVER - since a1 is a pointer, the copied pointers both point to the same memory.  Until you reassign p1.a1 to the address of "vshaj".

3) Don't ever, ever do anything like this in real code ;)

Comment: 1. `p1.a1` and `p.a1` *are* the same after the initialization of `p1`,  but not after `p1.a1` is reassigned.  2) What's wrong with this code?

Comment: he's assigning string literals to non-const `char *`.

Comment: That's perfectly legitimate, even in "real code".  What if you have to deal with one of the (many many many) APIs that don't have `const` correctness in their interfaces?  Better to have a simple `char *` and avoid casting in a thousand places in your code.

Comment: @Asap - 1) `p1=p;`: These are two different objects, p1 is a copy of p; they occupy different memory.  2) Both `p.a1` and `p1.a1` initially point to the same memory object.   So yes, they both point to the same memory object.  Right up until `p1.a1="vshaj";`.  3) Bad things can happen if you try to modify the contents of either p.a1 or p1.a1, because the string you're pointing to is a read-only string literal.  'Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do, until you reassign `p1.a1`, then of course they don't. You could just print them out to prove it.

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s
{
    char *a1;
    int a;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct s p = { "asdv", 11 };
    struct s p1 = p;

    printf("They're the same: %p %p\n", p.a1, p1.a1);

    p1.a1 = "vshaj";
    printf("%d %s\n",p.a,p.a1);

    printf("They're different: %p %p\n", p.a1, p1.a1);

    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
$ make example
cc     example.c   -o example
$ ./example 
They're the same: 0x10e258f2a 0x10e258f2a
11 asdv
They're different: 0x10e258f2a 0x10e258f48
```

Comment: is it possible if i make changes to p1.a1 and that changes are reflected in p.a1?

Comment: No, it's not.  `p1` and `p` are different objects.  You can point both at the same string and modify that string, if that's what you want.

Comment: If i use this function strupr(p1.a1) it gives runtime error.But if i make char array in struct it does not why?

Comment: That's because you're trying to modify a string literal, which causes undefined behaviour.  Don't do that.  There are hundreds (seriously, go look) of questions about just that on this site.